# is PodCIDR unique for each nodes?

Tags: kubernetes

Each node has a PodCIDR assigned, is it unique cross all nodes? I did a test on kind multiple nodes, looks like they are unique:

```
➜  ~ sh -x a.sh
+ kubectl describe nodes multi-nodes-worker
+ grep PodCIDRs
PodCIDRs:                     10.244.3.0/24
+ + grep PodCIDRs
kubectl describe nodes multi-nodes-worker2
PodCIDRs:                     10.244.5.0/24
+ grep PodCIDRs
+ kubectl describe nodes multi-nodes-worker3
PodCIDRs:                     10.244.4.0/24
+ kubectl describe nodes multi-nodes-worker4
+ grep PodCIDRs
PodCIDRs:                     10.244.1.0/24
+ kubectl describe nodes multi-nodes-worker5
+ grep PodCIDRs
PodCIDRs:                     10.244.2.0/24
```

Answer (score 1):

Unique CIDR range is assigned to each node by Flannel so that your pod IP is unique across the cluster and knowing which node to reach for a particular pod.